# in Kore.ai Dialog Task - How to allow user to upload and then submit a document via an API and update Workday?

Tags: json, file, upload, chatbot

We have an HR chatbot on the Kore.ai platform. I'm wondering if it's possible to allow a user to upload and submit a letter directly to our Workday HR system, using a dialog task.

We will be able to get the Workday integration through our internal TIS team to allow us to update Workday. However I don't know what is involved in the Dialog task.  Does anyone have an example of the code required within the Kore.ai platform to achieve this?  Any guidance is appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I’m sorry I just saw this post. You can add the letter as an attached file you can upload to the chatbot. Also, if you find it easier we can also create a form where the user explains the reasons, like a normal letter and update it to the system. Let me know if you would like to set up a quick meeting and go through all the options ☺️